# Нужен "перевод" с русского на php

Tags: php

Уважаемые гуру `PHP`. Ползал по просторам интернета в поисках одного скрипта.
Наткнулся-таки на интересный вариант. Может среди вас есть поклонники кино, и кто-то смотрел фильм "Социальная сеть". В самом начале фильма описывается создание сайта `"FACEMASH.COM"`. На сайте `"HABRAHABR.RU"` нашел скрипт этого сайта. [ВОТ](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/53991/).
В конце инструкции описывается файл `functions.php`. Вот его содержание:

```
    <? PHP
/ / Вычислить ожидаемый результат%
Ожидается функцию ($ Rb, Ra $) {
 возвращает 1 / (1 + ПР (10, ($ $ Rb-Ra) / 400));
}
/ / Вычислить новую оценку winnner
Функция выигрыша ($ оценка, $ ожидалось, $ K = 24) {
 вернуть $ оценка + $ K * (1 - $ ожидалось);
}
/ / Вычислить новую счетом проиграл
функция потерь ($ оценка, $ ожидалось, $ K = 24) {
 вернуть $ оценка + $ K * (0 - $ ожидалось);
}
>
```

Вопрос по тем не понятным описаниям, содержащимся ВНУТРИ кода.
Если кому не сложно, переведите, пожалуйста, в `php`.

Answer (score 2):

Загоняете в гугл-транслейт(что, видимо, сделал автор) и чуууууть-чуть правите:

```
// Calculate the expected result%
function expected($Rb, $Ra ) {
  return 1 / (1 + PR (10, ($Rb-$Ra) / 400));
}
// Calculate the new estimate winnner
function win ($price, $expected, $K = 24) {
  return $price + $K * (1 - $expected);
}
// Calculate new account lost
function loss ($price, $expected, $K = 24) {
  return $price + $K * (0 - $expected);
}
```

А зачем вам это?

Comment: Как и любому начинающему программисту, мне просто интересно :)

Comment: Я тоже не очень въехал, почему он перевел этот кусок текста на русский. Но, видимо, он вообще особо не заморачивался со статьей, судя по качеству русских комментариев к коду

Comment: Поправил имена функций в соответствии со статьей

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Очень помогли. Правда, я его порпавил, но он все равно капризничает

Comment: Будем разбираться